# missing jni folder in cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, java-native-interface

I'm using a third party library that has a folder armeabi-v7a with a .so file.
And I'm building a Cordova Plugin that uses that previous library I mentioned.

Unfortunately the project for which i build the plugin also has some jni files, but has additional folders like `arm64-v8a`, `x86_64`.

When I deploy the project to an Android like a Samsung S6 edge I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/<bla bla>/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/<bla bla>/lib/arm64, /data/app/<bla bla>/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "lib_so.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
at org.<bla bla>.<clinit>(SomeClass.java:22)
at lib.<bla bla>(SomeClass.java:185)
at lib.<bla bla>.SomeClass.access$200(SomeClass.java:47)
at lib.<bla bla>.SomeClass$1.run(SomeClass.java:149)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at lib.<bla bla>(AnotherClass.java:37)
```

I understand this is because of the library only providing it's .so on that one folder and i have other additional folders.

is there a way to fix this without involving the people who developed the library? Or is that the easies and/or only way?
i did try to add the lib in the plugin project but got dex merge errors when i try to add it to a project.

```
Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to fix this without involving the people who developed the library?

I am afraid the answer is **NO**.

This is because you need the source code in order to compile it into the **64-bit** arm ABI, i.e. `arm64-v8a` for your case.

Comment: i think you mean the answer is NO ,i cant fix with without the help of the lib developers, base on your description: I need the source code of the library to be compiled for this case.